# Two Enums implementing the same interface sharing a method

Tags: java, enums

I have two Enums implementing the same interface

```
public interface MetaEnum{
    String getDefaultValue();
    String getKey();
}

public enum A implements MetaEnum{
   ONE("1"), TWO("2");
   private String val;
   A(final v){
       val = v;
   }
   @Override
   public String getDefaultValue() {
       return value;
   }
   @Override
   public String getKey() {
        return (this.getClass().getPackage().getName() + "." + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "." +
            this.toString()).toLowerCase();
   }
}

public enum B implements MetaEnum{
   UN("1"), DEUX("2");
   private String val;
   B(final v){
       val = v;
   }
   @Override
   public String getDefaultValue() {
       return value;
   }
   @Override
   public String getKey() {
        return (this.getClass().getPackage().getName() + "." + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "." +
            this.toString()).toLowerCase();
   }
   ...other methods specific to this enum
}
```

I have duplicated code and I would like to avoid it. Is there a way to implement getKey in a sort of abstract class? I looked at this question [Java Enum as generic type in Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738133/java-enum-as-generic-type-in-enum) but it cannot adapt it to what I need.

Comment: Can you use java 8 ? `default` method would solve your trouble :)

Comment: yes, I am using Java 8. How would default help me ? :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *default method* from Java 8 should help you :)
This feature allows you to implement method inside an interface.

```
public interface MetaEnum {
  String getValue();  

  default String getKey() {
    return (this.getClass().getPackage().getName() + "." + 
            this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "." +
            this.toString()).toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, you can't implement a `default` method for getters, so you still have some duplicate code.

Comment: I did not know about the default method in java 8. It's exactly what I needed. Thx!

Answer (score 4):

Extract the common code to the separate class:

```
class MetaEnumHelper {
   private String val;

   MetaEnumImpl(final v){
       val = v;
   }

   public String getDefaultValue() {
       return value;
   }

   public String getKey(MetaEnum metaEnum) {
        return (metaEnum.getClass().getPackage().getName() + "." + metaEnum.getClass().getSimpleName() + "." +
            metaEnum.toString()).toLowerCase();
   }
}

public enum A implements MetaEnum{
   ONE("1"), TWO("2");
   private MetaEnumHelper helper;
   A(final v){
       helper = new MetaEnumHelper(v);
   }
   @Override
   public String getDefaultValue() {
       return helper.getDefaultValue();
   }
   @Override
   public String getKey() {
        return helper.getKey(this);
   }
}

public enum B implements MetaEnum{
   UN("1"), DEUX("2");
   private MetaEnumHelper helper;
   B(final v){
       helper = new MetaEnumHelper(v);
   }
   @Override
   public String getDefaultValue() {
       return helper.getDefaultValue();
   }
   @Override
   public String getKey() {
       return helper.getKey(this);
   }
   ...other methods specific to this enum
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer! It is an implementation of the Delegate pattern. Thank you ;)